# No Url Parameter on click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, url-parameters

I'm trying to follow this tutorial but reuse it for my own application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

However I'm having some issues when clicking the heading as explained in the tutorial my url is not changing to..

localhost:8000/Application?sortOrder=Date_desc

instead I just get the following

localhost:8000/Application

As a result sortOrder is always null and the sorting falls over to the default item in the switch.

Why is this happening? As far as I can see I have followed the tutorial. Can anyone explain where I might be going wrong?

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSortParam = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Name_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.AppSSortParm = sortOrder == "AppS" ? "AppS_desc" : "AppS";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        var applications = from a in db.applications select a;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            applications = applications.Where(s => s.applicationDescription.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Name_desc":
                applications = applications.OrderByDescending(s => s.applicationDescription);
                break;
            case "AppS_desc":
                applications = applications.OrderByDescending(s => s.applicationWindowSecurity);
                break;
            case "AppS":
                applications = applications.OrderBy(s => s.applicationWindowSecurity);
                break;
            default:
                applications = applications.OrderBy(s => s.applicationDescription);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 8;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(applications.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

View

```
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("App Description", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("App Sec Over", "Index")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("App Window Sec", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.AppSSortParm }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    </th>
```

Comment: Your actionLink parameters don't seem to match the parameters of your action method in your controller

Comment: You sure that `ViewBag.NameSortParm` and `ViewBag.AppSSortParm` are neither null nor an empty string right ? (i don't know what'd happen if they were, just a guess)

Comment: jazza1000 spot on changed "NameSortParm" to "NameSortParam" and problem solved, please change your comment to an answer and Ill accept it.

Comment: This is off-topic, but in my opinion.. dealing with view-related tasks in the controller is bad practice.. it creates confusion and doesn't separate concerns.  Furthermore, now you have multiple lines of code in your controller that strictly deal with paging, sorting, and filtering a table on a view..  there are javascript libraries that you can use that do all of this for you with one line of code.. look into [jQuery Datatable](https://www.datatables.net/manual/).  A lot easier to maintain, and only takes one line of code to setup.  Plus all of it stays in the view, not the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match the parameters in the actionLink with what you are expecting in your controller Action method. Note that ViewBag is a dynamic object which makes it very easy to make this kind of mistake (because it checks members at runtime rather than compile time).